# Debian installation hangs at final GRUB install: "Looking for other operating systems"

Tags: debian, grub, uefi, debian-installer

I used Rufus to burn Debian 9.2 NetInstall ISO to a USB. No matter what options I choose on Rufus, I always run into the same problem when installing Debian. When it gets to installing GRUB, it hangs at 16% on "Looking for other operating systems."

I even tried burning the ISO file to the USB on another computer running Debian, using `dd`. Same problem.

When the installation hangs, I press 'Ctrl + Alt + F4' to bring up the terminal.  It showed an extremely fast scrolling of errors and messages. I used my iPhone to take slow-motion video of the terminal messages as they zoomed by.

Here are a few stills showing the messages and errors I get:
[image]

The errors seem to be about being unable to find certain directories? I'm on a Dell Inspiron 13 7000 Series laptop.

Why does the install hang? What do these errors means? How do I fix this and get on with the Debian installation?

Comment: I can't give you an answer to your specific case but in my experience Rufus frequently creates unbootable or corrupt usbs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the ESP partition on your system disk is slightly corrupted: the directory entry `/EFI/dell/logs` has a pointer back to itself, creating an apparently infinitely deep directory tree. This is a relatively common problem on FAT-type filesystems. (The filesystem on the ESP partition is essentially FAT32.)

The installer is trying to search through all the directories on the ESP partition, but because of the corrupted directory, this search is stuck in an infinite loop.

You should try booting from the install media to rescue mode, identify the ESP partition and then run a filesystem check (fsck.vfat) on it. The filesystem check tool is likely to report a problem with either the `/EFI/dell` or `/EFI/dell/logs` directory. It might even suggest deleting the directory: deleting `/EFI/dell/logs` is probably fine, but you might want to recreate it afterwards, just to be sure.

In a rescue environment, the full path would be something like `/target/boot/efi/EFI/dell/logs`, as the root filesystem is mounted under `/target` while in rescue mode, and the ESP partition is mounted under `/boot/efi` while the system is running normally.

If the ESP filesystem is read-only in rescue mode, that's another indication that something is wrong with it. Typically ESP is the first partition on the first disk, or `/dev/sda1`. Run `cat /proc/mounts` in rescue mode to see the device name mounted to `/target/boot/efi`, then `umount /target/boot/efi` to unmount it, and then e.g. `fsck.vfat /dev/sda1` to check it for errors.

Comment: The directory is on /dev/sda. I booted the USB into Rescue Mode and opened a shell in the installer environment. When I tried running ‘rm -rf target/EFI/dell/logs’, the terminal gave an error saying it’s a read-only directory. How can I remove the directory?

Comment: The full path in the rescue environment should be something like `target/boot/efi/EFI/dell/logs`, as the ESP partition is usually mounted under `/boot/efi` and in rescue mode the root filesystem is mounted under `target`.

Comment: I just saw your edit. When I ran `cat /proc/mounts`, here's what I see: https://i.imgur.com/JeFp0fi.jpg. I don't see any device mounted at `/target/boot/efi`. Also, while running the shell in rescue mode on `/dev/sda1`, I cannot execute `fsck.vfat`. The command is not recognized... Or I ran it wrong.

Comment: Looks like the rescue mode is mounting a VFAT (that Linux filesystem type includes FAT32) onto just `/target`. That's probably the ESP. So you'd need to unmount that (generally never `fsck` a filesystem that is mounted) and then find a way to run a `fsck` command appropriate to FAT filesystems on /dev/sda1. The command name might also be `fsck.fat` or `dosfsck`: run `ls /sbin/*fsck*` while in rescue mode to look for likely candidates.

Comment: I ran `umount target`. I ran `ls /sbin/*fsck*` and found that `fsck.fat` is what I wanted. I ran `fsck.fat /dev/sda1`. The console asked if I wanted to correct or delete corrupted files and folders. I typed my agreement into the console. I rebooted my machine and successfully installed Debian 9.3.

Comment: Great! On a fully installed system, there is usually `/sbin/fsck.fat` and symlinks to it with names `dosfsck` and `fsck.vfat`. On an installer/rescue media, the symlinks are sometimes omitted.

Answer (score 0):

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>
2. `ps | grep grub-mount`
3. kill the process
4. if hangs again，repeat 2. 3.